# java fire action upon database stored time

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, t-sql

I am developing a java servlet that fires some action at some specified time, and because i will have many users, i think i should store user-id and time to fire action in database instead of memory.

So i need to track the time in database to fire such action, i have to ways
1- to query every minute on this time and check whether it is now or have passed to fire this action. or

2- to do stored procedure/trigger in the database to notify my servlet that now is the time to fire action.

how can i do any of these specially the second approach can t-sql do it or what else can do it ? 
what is the pros and cons of each approach ? is there a better approach you recommend ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer storing it in database and let database do a call to your servlet when required, this way you don't need to do polling logic in your web app, which will save lot of resources. For this approach, if it is Oracle database I remember there is a webservice call mechanism (It is been awhile I have implemented this, so I forgot exact naming convention). I think that is best approach.

Comment: isn't debugging these database call would be hard in compare to debugging an application client code ??

Comment: No. debugging difficulty is same every where and it is one time. But runtime we get more advantage.